# which is the best sorting method? To sort using array or dictionary sort? If array or dictionary, why so?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

which is the best sorting method? To sort using array or dictionary sort? If array or dictionary, why so?

Answer (score 3):

That largely depends on whether or not the data you want to sort is in an array (i.e.: a single dimension of data) or a dictionary (a set of key/value pairs).

i.e.: The "best" approach is one that fits the data, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have tagged this question with "Objective-C", you should use one of the sort methods built into `NSArray` to do your sorting.  It's a waste of time to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort is the fastest in most cases.  (Complex to implement).

But merge sort is good enough for most cases.  (Simpler to implement).

For algorithms for each you can use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort is the fastest and that is whi I use it so maybe that will help.